# AWS S3 key issue for uploaded file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've a question on S3 file key. I'm uploading an image file with the key being the url of the image. Here's the code snippet.

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
PutObjectRequest putObj = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET, KEY, createInputStream(IMAGE_PATH), createMetadata("image/jpeg"));
putObj.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
PutObjectResult result = s3.putObject(putObj);
```

Now, here's a sample key : **image/staging/file/GUID1234**

and the image name : **test.jpeg**

Now, this is how it looks like in S3 after the upload.
**TestBucket/image/staging/file/GUID1234**

There's no reference of the image name. The image url shows up as **http://TestBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image/staging/file/GUID1234**

As you can see, there's no reference of the image name, though it shows up the image in the browser correctly. I need to embed this url in a html page, and it doesn't lool ok if the image name is missing.

Just wondering, if there's a way to preserve the image name so that the url looks like **http://TestBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image/staging/file/GUID1234/test.jpeg**

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With S3, the `KEY` should be the **entire** name that you want the object to have. In your case, it appears (I don't know for sure since you have not included that code) that `KEY = image/staging/file/GUID1234`. If you want the object to be named image/staging/file/GUID1234/test.jpeg, then you will need to set the value of `KEY` to be `image/staging/file/GUID1234/test.jpeg`

Comment: Well, I need to retrieve the image based on the url, which is the key for me. Since, I don't know the name of the image during the retrieval process, it won't be possible for me to construct the key. I was trying to avoid browsing through thousands of keys and do a partial match.